Connecting SQL Server to nodejs
My current js node code:
const sql = require('mssql')
const sqlConfig = {
  user: 'sa',
  password: '12345678',
  database: 'mementoDB',
  server: 'LAPTOPSZKOLA\\SQLEXPRESS',
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: false,
    trustServerCertificate: true
  }
}

const func = async () => {
 try {
  await sql.connect(sqlConfig);
  const result = await sql.query(`select * from People`);
  console.dir(result);
 } catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
 }
}
func();

My error:

ConnectionError: Failed to connect to LAPTOPSZKOLA\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms
at C:\Users\creat\OneDrive\Pulpit\jsapps\tut2\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:85:17
at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\creat\OneDrive\Pulpit\jsapps\tut2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:838:9)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
at Connection.emit (node:events:514:28)
at Connection.emit (C:\Users\creat\OneDrive\Pulpit\jsapps\tut2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:959:18)
at Connection.connectTimeout (C:\Users\creat\OneDrive\Pulpit\jsapps\tut2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1209:10)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\creat\OneDrive\Pulpit\jsapps\tut2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1154:12)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
code: 'ETIMEOUT',
originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to LAPTOPSZKOLA\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms
at Connection.connectTimeout (C:\Users\creat\OneDrive\Pulpit\jsapps\tut2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1209:26)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\creat\OneDrive\Pulpit\jsapps\tut2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1154:12)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
code: 'ETIMEOUT'
}
}

My SQL Server:
db structure and working query

SQL Server Express edition commonly isn't even listening on a TCP port and so could not be connected to from NodeJS processes. Have you opened SQL Server 2022 Configuration Manager and checked the SQL Server Network Configuration of the SQLEXPRESS instance to ensure that the TCP/IP server protocol is enabled? If you make any changes in here you need to restart both the SQLEXPRESS instance as well as the SQL Browser service.

I have now enabled TCP/IP and restarted first server then even whole computer but I am still getting timed out error

".\SQLEXPRESS"
or
"localhost"
Find out host name by using SELECT @@SERVERNAME

SELECT @@SERVERNAME returns same thing I used just in lowercase
.\SQLEXPRESS gives error:
ConnectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .
and localhost gives error:
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)

@Creatos Check configuration manager: 1.Open SQL Server Configuration Manager and check if the SQL Server instance is running. 2.Ensure the SQL Server Browser service is running. 3.Check the TCP/IP settings. Ensure TCP/IP is enabled and that the port is set correctly.

I've got it!!
my "SQL Server Browser" service wasn't running. If you are having similar issue you can run this service in "Sql Server Configuration Manager"
